# Accessing iOS music library

Tags: ios, itunes

I have been programming for iOS for a while. It is simply out of my passion for learning new things. Recently I was trying to access the music files that are transferred to iPhone using iTunes. I could use the mediaPlayer to access them and play the music. I was wondering if there is a way to access the core mp3 files and upload them to a personal server. This is not for an app or something, but just a new learning about iOS.

Thanks in advance,
Videep

Comment: This is easily possible if you jailbreak, though some of the files may have DRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine, for obvious copyright reasons, that you're not allowed to do this. You are able to play it because the owner of the phone owns the song and it's playing for himself, but you are certainly not allowed to upload the mp3 of the whole library of all your customers to your server...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am quite convinced with this. Thanks!